# Почему selector внутри useSelector запускается дважды во время исполнения компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render, react-hook

[Ссылка на пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-architecture-60hcu?file=/src/index.js:407-849)

```
const selector = (state) => {
  console.log("invoke Selector");

  return state;
};

function App() {
  console.log("render App");

  const count = useSelector(selector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })}>Decrement</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ получен на англоязычной версии [сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827794/why-does-the-selector-inside-useselector-run-twice)